# Loading Properties files in an applet

Tags: java, resources, properties, applet

New to Applets, I have never dealt with having to export the resources to the jar.

The browser is failing to load properties files:

```
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission"
"config\en-us.properties""read")
```

Properties files are imported as so:

[image]

Code to load Properties file:

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config/en-us.properties"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtain an URL to the properties file in the jar using:

```
URL urlToProps = this.getClass().getResource("/config/en-us.properties");
```

Use an `URLConnection` to set a read timeout.

```
// courtesy of MyTitle 'default timeout is infinity'
URLConnection connection = urlToProps.openConnection(); 
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
```

Get an `InputStream`.

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

Then use [`Properties.load(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) to load it.

```
prop.load(is);
```

Comment: It is really that using `openStream()` is not recommended, because default  timeout is infinity? I heard that prefer way is to do like this: 

  `URL d = new URL("");
  URLConnection connection = d.openConnection();
  connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();`